# How can you quickly get the complete path to a file for use in terminal?

Tags: command-line, files, paths

How can you quickly get the complete path to a file for use in terminal?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Just drag and drop the file in the terminal.

Comment: I'm putting this here so that I don't forget, let's hope it helps some of you :D

Comment: Returns an "smb://" prefixed path for SMB mounted shares instead of the actual mounted path.

Comment: @Kupiakos: for me, gnome-terminal happily translates the dropped file path to `'/home/alexcohn/.gvfs/…'`

Answer (score 65):

```
readlink -f foo.bar
```

or (install it first)

```
realpath foo.bar
```

Comment: This answer is more accurate than one accepted.

Comment: For the complete folder: `ls | xargs realpath`.

Comment: The downside of `readlink` is that it will work even if the file doesn't exist. This can perpetuate bugs in very odd ways.

Comment: to copy the path to the os clipboard `realpath foo.bar | xclip -selection c`

Answer (score 13):

All good answers; Here is a tip for another situation.

If you are browsing your files using nautilus and you want the complete path of your current directory, then press `CTRL+L`. This changes the breadcrumb buttons temporarily back to the old-style address bar, allowing you to copy the path.

Comment: … but this is still `smb://`-style, so it cannot be reused in terminal.

Comment: Interesting; on my system (Ubuntu 13.10) I do not get a `smb://`-style path.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, I mean the terminal is a great place to ls but there is those times you work in a file folder views : ' )

Answer (score 4):

If it's an executable, then execute (in a terminal):

`$ which your_executable`

For example: `$ which ls`

Comment: This is the answer i was looking for

Answer (score 1):

In addition to dragging the icon, there are a few ways to get the full path without nautilus (or thunar, konqueror, et al.).   You would then triple-click or click-drag and copy, potentially saving this in your clipboard manager*, and paste it where you need.
(pastie, klipper, glippy, glipper, anamnesis)

- You can use `find` in a directory above your file.  (If you don't know where it is, start where your shell drops you, [generally] in the top of your home directory.)
  `find . | egrep filename`
- You can use `locate` to get the filename.  (Run `sudo updatedb` if that hasn't been done recently.)

A more realistic example of using find would be something like :

```
$ find | egrep askubuntu | grep txt
./askubuntu-temp.txt
./drDocuments/web/meta.askubuntu.txt
./other/stuff/askubuntu.txt.iteration.1
./other/stuff/askubuntu.txt.iteration.2
[...]
```

To cut out the ones you don't like, e.g.:

```
find | egrep askubuntu | grep txt | egrep -v iteration
find | egrep askubuntu | grep txt | egrep -v 'iteration|meta|other'
```

locate is used much the same way, though grep is frequently more necessary:

```
locate myfile | egrep home | egrep -v 'mozilla|cache|local|bin|\.pyc|test' | grep \.py
```

This isn't the most efficient way to type this, but usually if I've lost a file, I do this iteratively, adding grep clauses as I go.

Answer (score 1):

Easily done in python using `os.realpath()` function:

```
$ python -c 'import os,sys;print(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[1]))' ./VirtualBox\ VMs/                                      
/mnt/HDD/VirtualBox VMs
```

From a [related answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/871477/295286),you can also use `readlink`

```
$ readlink -e ./out.txt                                                                                                  
/home/username/out.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply copy a file in Nautilus, then the full path is copied.
Then paste it in the terminal. 
By simply pasting you get:

```
file:///home/juan/2017/agenda20170101.html
```

If you right-click and choose "Paste filenames" then you get:

```
'/home/juan/2017/agenda20170101.html'
```

with the quotes as shown.
This differs from Windows, that copies the file content instead of its name.