# Problem while installing Visual Paradigm UML Tool?

Tags: 13.10, tools, uml

I want to install Visual Paradigm community edition on Ubuntu 13.10. I follow the instruction on [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YRfYEvBP4Ko), but I cannot understand it.
Using terminal:

```
zeb@zeb-Lenovo-B570:~$ sudo -s
root@zeb-Lenovo-B570:~# '/home/zeb/Desktop/Visual_Paradigm_for_UML_CE_Linux_11_0_20140308.sh' -c
bash: /home/zeb/Desktop/Visual_Paradigm_for_UML_CE_Linux_11_0_20140308.sh: Permission denied
```

I also follow instruction  [Installing Visual Paradigm for UML on Linux and Unix](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/support/documents/vpumluserguide/12/14/6043_linuxandunix.html), it give:

```
zeb@zeb-Lenovo-B570:~$ bash ./%Visual_Paradigm_for_UML_CE_Linux_11_0_20140308.sh%
bash: ./%Visual_Paradigm_for_UML_CE_Linux_11_0_20140308.sh%: No such file or directory
```

Can anybody tell me the proceedure that how to install Visual Paradigm tool on Ubuntu 13.10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
zeb@zeb-Lenovo-B570:~$ bash ./%Visual_Paradigm_for_UML_CE_Linux_11_0_20140308.sh%
bash: ./%Visual_Paradigm_for_UML_CE_Linux_11_0_20140308.sh%: No such file or directory
```

If you give the code like this, bash try to search for the file inside the current directory and execute  if it exists.If the file doesn't be exists on the current directory then it shows `No such file or directory` error.And also you have to give the exact filename.If you fails to give that, then there comes the error `No such file or directory`.

So it's safe to give the filename along with their path while executing.

Syntax:

```
zeb@zeb-Lenovo-B570:~$ sudo bash /path/exact-filename.sh
```

Your command should be,

```
zeb@zeb-Lenovo-B570:~$ sudo bash /home/zeb/Desktop/Visual_Paradigm_for_UML_CE_Linux_11_0_20140308.sh
```

OR

```
zeb@zeb-Lenovo-B570:~$ sudo -s
root@zeb-Lenovo-B570:~# bash /home/zeb/Desktop/Visual_Paradigm_for_UML_CE_Linux_11_0_20140308.sh
```

[How can you quickly get the complete path to a file for use in terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23413/how-can-you-quickly-get-the-complete-path-to-a-file-for-use-in-terminal)