# Show full path to file in terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, files, paths

I have a file. I'd like to echo out the full path to it in the terminal.

Which command would?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found it:

```
sudo apt-get install realpath
```

Then:

```
realpath MY_FILE
```

Comment: You can use `locate` command from `mlocate` package as well.

Comment: Imho it's not necessary to install something for *that* kind of task ..

Comment: @StefanFalk Care to answer with a very easy solution then?) I don't like this either but it's quick and shows me what I need.

Comment: Rahu and Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy already provided two answers which do not require the installation of an additional program. :)

Comment: `realpath` is part of coreutils, and as such should already be available on 99% of systems running Linux.

Answer (score 27):

Use `readlink` with `-e` flag. Not only it gives you full path to file, it also presents real path of the symlinks

```
$ readlink -e ./out.txt                                                                                                  
/home/xieerqi/out.txt
```

I personally use it in my own scripts whenever it's necessary to get full path of a file

Comment: $ readlink -e README.md 

readlink: illegal option -- e

usage: readlink [-n] [file ...]

Comment: @KarlMorrison Are you using Ubuntu ? Ubuntu uses GNU version of readlink which has that option. BSD and Mac os don't

Answer (score 5):

*If you don't know the location of the file use `find` command.*

`find / -name MY_FILE`

It will print full path of `MY_FILE` starting from `/`.

or you can use 
`find $PWD -name MY_FILE`
to search in current directory.

If you know the location of `MY_FILE` then go to folder containg `MY_FILE` and use

`pwd` command to print the full path of `MY_FILE`.

Comment: For searchin in current directory you can also use `find $PWD -name` instead of `find . -name`, and all the resutls will include the real path instead of the `./` symbol.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou Thanks for feedback. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function to show paths to files, you may just need the "fpath=...." part ?

```
pathtofile () { : "gives full path to files given in parameters.";
  for f in "$@"; do
    fpath="$(
      cd -P "$(dirname "$f")" && \
      printf '%s\n' "$(pwd)/$(basename "${f}")" || \
      { echo "__An error occured while determining path to file: '${f}'."\
             "Maybe your user can't access its directory, most likely?__"
      }  )"
    printf "Full path to: %s\n          is: %s\n" "'${f}'" "'${fpath}'";
  done
}
```

Use with:

```
pathtofile   file1  ../file2  /some/pathwithsymlink/file3
```

The important part: cd -P somedir : shows the full "real" path to somedir.