# How to copy the path of current directory in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: nautilus

How to get the path of directory in ubuntu 18.04. Such as clicking on title bar in windows.

Comment: I am not talking about terminal. I know its PWD command

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you quickly get the complete path to a file for use in terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23413/how-can-you-quickly-get-the-complete-path-to-a-file-for-use-in-terminal)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I guess you are looking for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.
When you are in the file-browser, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and the path appears at the top.

Comment: yes Exactly thank you

Comment: @Haider Yaqoob When you find an answer which is helpful, please click on the up arrowhead to its left. When you find a complete answer that solves your issue, please _also_ click on the checkmark to show a complete solution, so other folks w/ the same issue are led there.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the directory then properties and you can see it under "Parent folder:"

Answer (score 2):

I created an extension for this. You can copy path and name:

https://github.com/chr314/nautilus-copy-path

[image: Copy Path]

Comment: This is a very good tool. Thank you. For me, using the Ctrl+L features is decent, but not great. I usually need to copy a path to a specific file or folder to paste elsewhere. This tool gets that done and is easy to set up. +1

Answer (score 2):

To permanently enable it on the nautilus window of Ubuntu18.04, use the following command:

`gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences always-use-location-entry true`

But, I still have a question that on the older versions of Ubuntu, one can easily enable the path visibility/editing feature from the browser '**upload**' window and easily change the path by pasting the path. Is there any way to do so directly in the new OS?

Thank you.